# Bash script to find specific files older than 90 days and put them in .csv file

Tags: bash, file, directory, find

I have the bash script below, and I am trying to find a way to write additional functionality that also calculates the number of days between the last modification of the file and the current date:

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p "do you want to find the files? Y/N " -n 1 -r
echo

echo "path , $(date +%d-%m-%Y)" >> checked_files.csv
find . -name "data.csv" | xargs -d '\n' stat -c "%-25n;%y" | echo "$(date +%d-%m-%Y) - $(stat 
-c "%-25n;%y")" | bc >> checked_files.csv
find . -name "output_for_CPA_tool.csv" | xargs -d '\n' stat -c "%-25n;%y" >> checked_files.csv
find . -name "info_table.csv" | xargs -d '\n' stat -c "%-25n;%y" >> checked_files.csv
find . -name "int_2.csv" | xargs -d '\n' stat -c "%-25n;%y" >> checked_files.csv
find . -name "intermediate.csv" | xargs -d '\n' stat -c "%-25n;%y" >> checked_files.csv
find . -name "output_for_MME_tool.csv" | xargs -d '\n' stat -c "%-25n;%y" >> checked_files.csv
find . -name "media_contacts.csv" | xargs -d '\n' stat -c "%-25n;%y" >> checked_files.csv
find . -name "modeldata.csv" | xargs -d '\n' stat -c "%-25n;%y" >> checked_files.csv
find . -name "modeldata.RData.csv" | xargs -d '\n' stat -c "%-25n;%y" >> checked_files.csv
```

Comment: Update your question with only one csv. Do you have an error? How the expected value should be showed?

Comment: Tks @JRichardsz

Answer (score 0):

you can use :

```
datediff() {
    d1=$(date -d "$1" +%s)
    d2=$(date -d "$2" +%s)
    echo $(( (d1 - d2) / 86400 )) days
}
```

in your case you can calculate days like below (by adding above lines in your script):

```
datediff "$(date +%F)" "`find . -name "modeldata.csv" | xargs -d '\n' stat -c "%-25n;%y" | cut -d";" -f2 | awk '{print $1}' | head -n 1`"
```

so for complete way you can write your commands :

```
#!/bin/bash

datediff() {
    d1=$(date -d "$1" +%s)
    d2=$(date -d "$2" +%s)
    echo $(( (d1 - d2) / 86400 )) days
}

result1=`find . -name "modeldata.csv" | xargs -d '\n' stat -c "%-25n;%y" | awk '{print $1}'`
datediff1=$(datediff "$(date +%F)" "`find . -name "modeldata.csv" | xargs -d '\n' stat -c "%-25n;%y" | cut -d";" -f2 | awk '{print $1}' | head -n 1`")
echo "$result1 $datediff1" >> checked_files.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Suggesting single `find` command, filtered by an `awk` script.

```
 find . -regextype egrep -regex "(data|output_for_CPA_tool|info_table|int_2|intermediate|output_for_MME_tool|media_contacts|modeldata|modeldata.RData)\.csv" -printf "%p %CY-%Cj $(date +%Y-%j)\n" | awk -F "[ -]" '{print $1, (($4*365)+$5)-(($2*365)+$3)}' >> checked_files.csv
```

But if you just want the files older than 90 days, without the counted days.

`-ctime +90`  will filter all files with change time larger than 90 days.

So that the `find` command becomes:

```
  find . -regextype egrep -regex "(data|output_for_CPA_tool|info_table|int_2|intermediate|output_for_MME_tool|media_contacts|modeldata|modeldata.RData)\.csv" -ctime +90 >> checked_files.csv
```

#### Stage 1, build a list of required files with dates of last change and current date

Suggesting to use single `find` command:

```
find . -regextype egrep -regex "(data|output_for_CPA_tool|info_table|int_2|intermediate|output_for_MME_tool|media_contacts|modeldata|modeldata.RData)\.csv" -printf "%p %CY-%Cj $(date +%Y-%j)\n"
```

##### Expected response list of all files

Suggested selective list:

```
<files_relative_path> <year_last_change>-<day_num_in_year> <curr_year>-<curr_day_in_year>
./dir1/modeldata.csv 2022-013 2022-069
./dir2/info_table.csv 2022-013 2022-069
./dir3/modeldata.csv 2022-013 2022-069
./dir3/data.csv 2022-013 2022-069
./dir1/output_for_MME_tool.csv 2022-013 2022-069
```

#### Stage 2, compute day difference and print it out

```
awk -F "[ -]" '{print $1, (($4*365)+$5)-(($2*365)+$3)}'
```

##### Expected response list of all files

Suggested selective list:

```
<files_relative_path> <days_since_last_change>
./dir1/modeldata.csv 0
./dir2/info_table.csv 12
./dir3/modeldata.csv 21
./dir3/data.csv 376
./dir1/output_for_MME_tool.csv 231
```

#### Stage 3, Redirect output to `>> checked_files.csv`

### Detailed explanation

#### `find` command details

`.`  Start looking from current directory down.

`-regextype egrep`   Set regular expression interpreter to `egrep`

`-regex "(data|output_for_CPA_tool|info_table|int_2|intermediate|output_for_MME_tool|media_contacts|modeldata|modeldata.RData)\.csv"`  A regular expression name filter that match all required file names.

`-printf "%p %CY-%Cj $(date +%Y-%j)\n"`  Output for each file: `%p` file's relative path, `%CY` year of last change, `%Cj` day in year of last change, `$(date +%Y-%j)` current day in format `YYYY-jjj`, `jjj` stand for current day in year.

#### `awk` command details

`-F "[ -]"`  Set `awk`'s field separator to either   or `-`. So there will be 5 fields.

`{print $1, (($4*365)+$5)-(($2*365)+$3)}` Output `$1` that is file's relative path. Than calculate difference of days. `$4` is current year, `$5` is current day in year, `$2` year of last change, `$3` day in year of last change.